# Отдать файл в браузер (на загрузку) JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, файлы

Только начал изучать jquery и возник вопрос. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли через JS или AJAX отдать пользователю файл на загрузку? Файл в формате pdf.

На сайте есть форма, к этой форме привязан AJAX обработчик, который отправляет данные с формы на почту, можно в этом скрипте это реализовать?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form1").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(){
            $('#thanks').css('display', 'flex');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#modal").hide('slow'); 
                $('#thanks').css('display', 'none');
            }, 2000);

        }
    });
});
});
```

Всем спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Через blob, object uri и программный клик по ссылке. Но это только для современных.

Comment: Эта задача [уже решена в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998521/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5).